# How can I install Python libraries on Linux?

Tags: python

While I was installing Python libraries on Linux, it threw the below error. How can I fix it?

I ran the below command to install:

```
python setup.py install
```

Output:

```
running install
running build
running build_ext
error: pyconfig.h: No such file or directory
```

Comment: It would help to specify which distribution of Linux you're using. You're likely to have to install the Python development package (if the library you're trying to use requires it).

Answer (score 6):

The first thing to try is to install the appropriate module via your package manager. Each distro has many, many, many Python modules already packaged and ready to go.

If you insist on installing a module from source then you'll need the development package for your distro's Python. This is usually called `python-devel`, `python-dev`, or something similar. Use the package manager to install it.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, where to download package manager and how to install. Can you please let me know in detail as am new to python.

Comment: That is a Linux issue, not a Python issue.